# Table access - SQL (Java)

Tags: java, sql, list, iterator

Suppose I have a table MYtable as given below:

```
ID   A     B        C
1   100  APPLE     CAKE
2   200  BANANA    PIE
```

I want to be able to save all these table records into a list (of some kind) and iterate through each record.

Query would be :

```
select * from Mytable where ID in (1,2,3)
```

So,the list should have 2 records:
record1 should contain 1,100,APPLE,CAKE
and record2 should contain 2,200,BANANA,PIE

I also want to be able to iterate through each record

So for record1 - I want to getColumnA i.e 100, getColumnB i.e APPLE, and so on

Comment: Take a look at JDBC: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<YourObject> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
  while(rs.next()){
        int id = rs.getInt(1);
        int A = rs.getInt(2);
        String B= rs.getString(3);
        String C = rs.getString(4);
        YourObject ob = new YourObject (id, A, B, C);
        listOfObjects.add(ob); //now you have the list of objects .. iterate trough it
    }
```

Comment: here's a good article .. simple and clear: http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-mysql-select-query-example

Comment: :Thank you!I think this will be useful!

Answer (score 0):

First you will need [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) to connect to the database.

You can use [Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) or [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to fetch data from database and then you can get that data stored in [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

Now you can iterate through the results in ResultSet.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to implement JDBC.

After creating JDBC connection. Execute query and the fetch records from the resultset. From a record you can fetch particular columns as well.

see following example [how to work with jdbc basic](http://www.heimetli.ch/jdbc/JDBCQuery.html)

http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/

```
import java.sql.* ;

class JDBCQuery
{
 public static void main( String args[] )
 {
  try
     {
      // Load the database driver
      Class.forName( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" ) ;

      // Get a connection to the database
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Database" ) ;

      // Print all warnings
      for( SQLWarning warn = conn.getWarnings(); warn != null; warn = warn.getNextWarning() )
         {
          System.out.println( "SQL Warning:" ) ;
          System.out.println( "State  : " + warn.getSQLState()  ) ;
          System.out.println( "Message: " + warn.getMessage()   ) ;
          System.out.println( "Error  : " + warn.getErrorCode() ) ;
         }

      // Get a statement from the connection
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;

      // Execute the query
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "select * from Mytable where ID in (1,2,3)" ) ;

      // Loop through the result set
      while( rs.next() )
      {
         System.out.println( rs.getString('ID') ) ;
         System.out.println( rs.getString('A') ) ;
         System.out.println( rs.getString('B') ) ;
         System.out.println( rs.getString('C') ) ;
      }

      // Close the result set, statement and the connection
      rs.close() ;
      stmt.close() ;
      conn.close() ;
     }
  catch( SQLException se )
     {
      System.out.println( "SQL Exception:" ) ;

      // Loop through the SQL Exceptions
      while( se != null )
         {
          System.out.println( "State  : " + se.getSQLState()  ) ;
          System.out.println( "Message: " + se.getMessage()   ) ;
          System.out.println( "Error  : " + se.getErrorCode() ) ;

          se = se.getNextException() ;
         }
     }
  catch( Exception e )
     {
      System.out.println( e ) ;
     }
 }
}
```